# App Indexing and signed Android App with SHA-1

Tags: android, sha1, sha256, android-app-indexing

We have currently an Android App at Google Play with more than 100K downloads and thousands of ratings.
We want to add App Indexing and following the instructions from 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/public-content
we have to associate our site and our app using Digital Asset Links.
It requires SHA-256 but we have been signin the app with SHA-1.

How can we migrate from SHA-1 to SHA-256 without loosing all our downloads and ratings on Google Play as they explain at
https://guardianproject.info/2015/12/29/how-to-migrate-your-android-apps-signing-key/

Can we just add SHA-256 and maintain also SHA-1, so we don't loose our downloads and ratings?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your SHA 256 from your signing certificate using below command.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <signing_certificate>
```

It will display your certificate details with MD5, SHA1 and SHA256.